# Can I change react-admin layout per route?

Tags: react-admin

According to the documentation, react-admin supports having routes with no layout (the nolayout property), but is there some way to specify a different layout using the route system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. All the CRUD routes share the same layout. If you need a CRUD route with a particular layout, you'll have to define one custom route for each.

Comment: I consider custom routes to be part of react-admin, so your answer sounds more like a yes. However, you don't say how I should go about using custom routes for this. The only thing I find in the documentation is the nolayout property.

Comment: Custom routes are pure React components. there is nothing specific about react-admin there, so I dont see what you need us to document.

Comment: Ok, my misunderstanding, sorry. Since react-admin has explicit support for nolayout in custom routes, I took your initial answer to mean that I somehow could provide a layout through it too. Would it be a reasonable feature request? :)